# Using jest for test react-native - redux app

Tags: unit-testing, testing, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

I am trying to fill a Text Input and verify that the text is filled correctly, accessing the component and getting its value.

I have succeeded in doing so, but without using redux, ie using the native states of react-native. `this.state`.

**Component Code:**

```
//inside constructor
this.state = {
  email: ''
}

<TextInput value={this.state.email} onChangeText={(text) => {
  console.log('Here change email text!!! ==> ', text);
  this.setState({
    email: text
  })
}} />
```

**Test File Code:**

```
import LoginScreen from '../../App/Containers/LoginScreen' // => connected component.. exported with `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)`
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import Actions, { reducer, INITIAL_STATE } from '../../App/Redux/Reducers/UserReducer'


const initialState = {
  user: {
    email: 'mockState email',
    password: '',
    requesting: 0,
    userData: null,
    loginFinish: false,
    errorMessage: null
  }
}

const mockStore = configureStore([]);
let store = mockStore(initialState);

const wrapper = shallow(
  <LoginScreen/>,
  { context: { store: store } },
);

test('>>>>> LoginScreen component renders correctly', () => {
  expect(wrapper.dive()).toMatchSnapshot();
});


test('>>>>> Login button Press', () => {
  let render = wrapper.dive();

  const textInputProps = render.find('TextInput'); //getting text input from render
  console.log(`textInputProps.getNode(1).props.value BEFORE ====>`, textInputProps.getNodes()[0].props.value);

  textInputProps.first().simulate('changeText', 'My new value'); // executing onChangeText inside render of component

  const textInputProps2 = render.find('TextInput'); //getting text input again for check changes
  console.log(`textInputProps2.getNode(1).props.value====>`, textInputProps2.getNodes()[0].props.value); 

  const state = store.getState(); //verifying internal `initialState`.. NOT CHANGES
  console.log('state ===> ', state);

});
```

I have relied on [this link](https://medium.com/react-native-training/learning-to-test-react-native-with-jest-part-1-f782c4e30101)

**Running test logs**

```
yarn test v0.24.6
$ jest 
 PASS  Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js
  ✓ >>>>> LoginScreen component renders correctly (282ms)
  ✓ >>>>> Login button Press (33ms)

  console.log Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js:60
    textInputProps.getNode(1).props.value BEFORE ====> 

  console.log App/Containers/LoginScreen.js:124
    Here change email text!!! ==>  My new value

  console.log Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js:67
    textInputProps2.getNode(1).props.value====> My new value => (!!!WORKS!!!)

  console.log Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js:86
    state ===>  { user: 
       { email: 'mockState email',
         password: '',
         requesting: 0,
         userData: null,
         loginFinish: false,
         errorMessage: null } }

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        2.337s, estimated 3s
Ran all test suites.
✨  Done in 3.10s.
```

as you can see in the logs `textInputProps2.getNode(1).props.value ====>` show me the value as expected.

> ***So far so good***

Now passing everything to a reducer, with the redux structure, we will see the text input as follows

```
<TextInput value={this.props.user.email} style={styles.textInputs} placeholder={'Email'} autoCapitalize={'none'} onChangeText={(text) => {
  console.log('Here change email text!!! ==> ', text);
  this.props.email_typing(text);
}} />
```

*Connected logic*

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    email_typing: (text) => dispatch(UserReducer.email_typing(text)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

*My `UserReducer` File*

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  email_typing: ['email'],
})

export const LoginTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  email: ''
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */


// state.merge undefined error: https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/pull/20#issuecomment-202550408. Fixed including in Inmutable
export const emailTyping = (state, { email }) => {
  console.log('Email Typing changes !!! in original reducer')
  return Immutable(state).merge({ email })
}


/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.EMAIL_TYPING]: emailTyping,
})
```

Given this change, the idea is that the `initialState` within the **Test File** changes to `INITIAL_STATE` imported value.

Something like:

```
const mockStore = configureStore([]);
let store = mockStore(INITIAL_STATE);
```

but, when i run the test again. Show me the next error:

```
 ● >>>>> LoginScreen component renders correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

even if I keep the initialState instead of the INITIAL_STATE, I do not get the above error, but I can not get the text input to take the change.

***Running Test Logs***

```
yarn test v0.24.6
$ jest 
 PASS  Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js
  ✓ >>>>> LoginScreen component renders correctly (345ms)
  ✓ >>>>> Login button Press (24ms)

  console.log Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js:58
    textInputProps.getNode(1).props.value BEFORE ====> mockState email

  console.log App/Containers/LoginScreen.js:120
    Here change email text!!! ==>  My new value

  console.log Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js:61
    textInputProps2.getNode(1).props.value====> mockState email => **(!! HERE !!!, THE VALUE IS BEING THE PREVIOUS ONE AND IGNOR THE CHANGE)**

  console.log Tests/Containers/loginScreenTest.js:79
    state ===>  { user: 
       { email: 'mockState email',
         password: '',
         requesting: 0,
         userData: null,
         loginFinish: false,
         errorMessage: null } }

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        2.904s
Ran all test suites.
✨  Done in 3.68s.
```

Check `textInputProps2.getNode(1).props.value====>` log to check that this is not useful.

> I think that the `const initialState` declared inside `test file` It is not being affected by the changes made in the actual reducer when `this.props.email_typing(text)` action is called;

**I have not found the way to connect the actions with the states in the reducer and to be able to load them inside JEST.**

*I know it's a bit long and I appreciate your time reading it.
I tried to leave it the best explained and as much information as possible.
Thank you very much and I look forward to any response.*

Comment: import LoginScreen from '../../App/Containers/LoginScreen' // => connected component.. exported with `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)         this sounds like an import issue , did you export the component as well (you should have 2 exports in your tested file, one for the connect and one for the actual component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do some integration test here. It is possible to achieve what you are trying like that :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer } from '.../UserReducer';

// create a real store with the needed reducer(s)
const store = createStore(combineReducers({ user: reducer }));

const wrapper = shallow(
  <LoginScreen/>,
  { context: { store } },
);

// ...

test('>>>>> Login button Press', () => {
  let render = wrapper.dive();

  const textInputProps = render.find('TextInput');
  console.log(`value BEFORE ====>`, textInputProps.getNodes()[0].props.value);

  textInputProps.first().simulate('changeText', 'My new value');

  // Force the component to update after changing state 
  render = wrapper.update().dive();

  const textInputProps2 = render.find('TextInput');
  console.log(`value AFTER ====>`, textInputProps2.getNodes()[0].props.value); 

  const state = store.getState();
  console.log('state ===> ', state);
});
```

I tried with a minimal implementation, here is the console result:

```
console.log src/Test.test.js:27
value BEFORE ====> 

console.log src/Test.test.js:35
value AFTER ====> My new value

console.log src/Test.test.js:38
state ===>  { user: { email: 'My new value' } }
```

Comment: The change in state works fine, but `value AFTER` log still empty. I'm printing `this.props.user.email` inside of render from `LoginScreen` and still empty. But when i print `store.getState()` i can see the change

Comment: Works for me, if i call `shallow` again before `wrapper.update().dive();` It seems like something should not be needed, do you have any idea why?